# How to sync to tables in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access: `table1` and `table2`. In `table1` I have fields: ID, name (text), short_name (text), description (text), use_in_table2 (checkbox). In `table2` I have fields: ID, name (text), max (num), min (unm) and others. I want to copy object from `table1` to `table2` with use_in_table2 == *True*. Also if I reset checkbox use_in_table2 in `table1`, I will delete corresponding object from `table2`. I use same ID for same objects in both tables. I use simple python script for my task. How can I solve this problem in MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't do it this way.  Don't Repeat Yourself(DRY).  In most cases there is no need for Table 2.  Just create Table 2 every time you need it with a select query.  You can use the Query Designer to help you write the sql.  You can even hit make table and create a table rather than a query but for most purposes they work the same.
[image]

```
'select query
SELECT Table1.Table1ID, Table1.Month, Table1.X, Table1.Y, Table1.use_in_table2
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.use_in_table2)=True));

'make table query
SELECT Table1.Table1ID, Table1.Month, Table1.X, Table1.Y, Table1.use_in_table2 INTO Table2
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.use_in_table2)=True));
```

To answer the question posed.  Note the Delete and Update Tabs.  After Making Table2 you must run two queries rather than just 1.  A delete Query for records where use_in_table2 is false and an update query where use_in_table2 is true.  I ran out of time; look those up